# Quality reduces after UploadedFile.SaveAs("")

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am uploading a file (image) using `<asp:FileUpload />` and in the codebehind I use `UploadedFile.SaveAs("C://Path...")` to save the image on the server.

This is my complete code:

```
protected void btnAddImage_OnClick(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    //_fuImage is the ID of the <asp:FileUpload />
    _fuImage.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(fullPath));
}
```

The problem is that it seems to reduce the quality. Here are some examples: The left image is the one I want to upload and the right one is the one uploaded on the server.

[image: Example 1]
[image: Example 2]
[image: Example 3]

---

This worked thanks to Ashigore:

```
byte[] imageBytes = _fuImage.FileBytes;
File.WriteAllBytes(Server.MapPath(fullPath), imageBytes);
```

I've stored the bytes in a variable and saved the raw bytes to the server as an image file.

Comment: do you change image format ?

Comment: Nope I just use SaveAs(), not more not less, I do not modify anything.

Comment: are you simple uploading the image or are you doing operation like  making image smaller (means from 1024 x 1024 to may be 400 x 400)

Comment: I do not resize the images. I edited my question, this is all my code, take a look.

Comment: Are the images being displayed differently in any way between the two? `<img width="x" />` for example?

Comment: @StevenV The sizes stay exactly the same.

Comment: JPEG? PNG? GIF? Bitmap?

Comment: @StevenV All 3 uploaded images were JPEG files but as you can see they look pretty good **before** the upload

Comment: Those don't look worse, they look better. The contrast is higher.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is you are working with an Image object somewhere which converts the jpg data into raw bitmap data and re-encodes it when saving. You need to work with raw bytes only in such a way as they never get converted to an Image object in order to preserve the original quality.

Comment: But I use a standard `ASP.Net` method: `UploadedFile.SaveAs(string arg)` and that one doesn't convert anything.

Comment: Well, you would seem to be proving otherwise. Are you sure that all that happens to the images?

Comment: I posted all the code I use. But I am starting to think the `SaveAs("")` does indeed convert data. Do you know another method I can use that does not convert the bytes so I can save it exaclty as I upload it?

Comment: For the sake of argument, use FileUpload.FileBytes and use File.WriteAllBytes or a FileStream to save the data, see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Can you look at the file that was saved as a result of this operation directly on disk without using the website? Compare it to the original - Is there a difference?  You may be altering the image in some way when displaying it.

The alternative is to Use `FileUploadControl.OpenFile()` to get the stream, and manually write it out to disk.